# LEFT JOIN crossing with multiple keys

Tags: sql

Is there anyway to cross tables with 2 keys, in case the first one doesn't exist?

For example:

I have a LEFT table called **order** that contains a field called *key_1* and a RIGHT table called **pre_order** where *key_1* is the primary key. The thing is: due to systemic errors, not all registers from **order** contain a *key_1* value, even though they should. So, when left joining those tables, some data from my **pre_order** table will be missing.
If *key_1* is empty in the **order** table, I'd like it to cross with a different key. In this case, a *CONCAT* of multiple fields that are common to both tables, that would garantee an artificial primary key.

I thought about using *COALESCE*, but in a first glance, it wouldn't work.

The logic is:

*IF* *key_1* is not null nor empty, cross both tables with *key_1*

*ELSE*, cross it with a CONCAT of multiple common fields of both tables.

Unfortunately, it looks like the ON statement doesn't let me work freely around logic statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use case statement in on clause as below
On 1=case when isnull(table1.key_1,'')<>'' and isnull(table2.key_1)<>'' and table1.key_1 =table2.key_1 then 1
When (isnull(table1.key_1,'')<>'' or isnull(table2.key_1)<>'') and concat(table1.column1,column2)=concat(table.2.column1,column2) then 1 end

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. the query goes on and on forever.

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected output